# how to change Font dots mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, variable-fonts

I have a variable font and I want to use it in my project, but I can't use one of its options. This option changes the status of dots in Persian language

If anyone has a solution for it, please tell me , thanks

I used DefaultTextStyle and FontFeature but it didn't work.
i dont see a property for change dots mode

this is dots mode in my variable font : -
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in new version of sdk this is so easy
you must go to your Text >> Textstyle >> fontVariations
then you apply the changes

```
Text("سپه سالار ایران زمین", style : TextStyle(fontFamily : 
      "IRANYeaknXVF" ,
      fontSize : 18.0,
      fontVariations: const <FontVariation>[
         FontVariation("dots", 1), // Set any dot you want
         FontVariation("wght", 500), // Set any weight you want
      ],
   )
)
```

in **pubspec.yaml** you should import it like this :

```
    - family: IRANYekanXVF
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/iranYekanX/IRANYekanXVF.ttf
```

Comment: can you tell me what is font family weight used in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: no need to to define weight or dots weight be cause this a variable font.